# Is Reflection a disadvantage as private variables cannot be restricted?

Tags: security, reflection

The `private` modifier is used to restrict access outside the class, but using reflection other classes  can access private method and fields. So I am wondering how we can restrict accessibility if it is part of requirement.

Comment: Low trust code cannot use private reflection (at least not on other assemblies, I forgot the details). Full trust code can simply use pointers to bypass any restrictions within the process.

Comment: Private access modifiers mainly exist to tell programmers "don't use this from outside the class, and if you really do, don't complain if the next version breaks your code" not as strictly enforced security feature.

Comment: Google it, there are plenty of duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566626/how-to-restrict-developers-to-use-reflection-to-access-private-methods-and-const, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29246028/how-to-prevent-access-via-reflection, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18619754/java-preventing-reflection ...

Comment: Users can also just patch your code to do whatever they want.  With a partial exception for DRM (which is not powerful enough to provide enduring protection), anyone who has access to your application (binaries or source code) can do anything with it.

Comment: depending on the language reflection is relatively more expensive than direct references as well, if performance is a concern.  Of course it depends on what you're doing (tests or app startup are going to be OK)

Comment: If you are talking about Java you can restrict reflection with a security manager and upcoming java 9 module isolation (akastrong encapsulation).

Comment: Isn't this a language specific question?  Reflection operates differently in different languages.  I'm wondering if this question should have a tag for Java or something else.

Comment: @WayneConrad: yes this is both language-specific and language-version-specific. I tagged [tag:java] and you can all please tag with other relevant languages.

Answer (score 54):

The purpose of access modifiers is to inform developers writing code about what is the public interface of a class. They are not in any way a security measure and they do not literally hide or secure any information.

Comment: This is not universally true.  Quoting [Eric Lippert](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/03/28/why-cant-i-access-a-protected-member-from-a-derived-class-part-two-why-can-i/#div-comment-4799), "Access modifiers in the CLR are security features. The rules for access are thoroughly conflated with the security and type safety systems.  " In C#, Reflection is only available to code running under full trust.  This does not (and cannot) apply to malicious users of the system who are *running* the code.  However, it does apply to malicious plug-ins.

Comment: @Brian Where the issue Brian mentions is relevant is when a system allows third-party code to run on without fully trusting it.  Examples include browser sand-boxes (e.g. the much hated applet), [google app engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs) and [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-otnet-get-started/).  It would be really stupid for Azure to allow untrusted code to explore the details of the platform's core libraries.

Comment: @Brian That's not 100% correct - there are some reflection operations you can do in partially trusted code; it just doesn't allow you to do things like accessing private fields.

Comment: @Brian Until someone finds a vulnerability or social engineering that allows them to bypass the restrictions. There is no point in trying to use them that way. That is not their primary purpose.

Answer (score 31):

To quote [Herb Sutter on class access rights](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/076.htm):

"The issue here is of protecting against Murphy vs. protecting against Machiavelli... that is, protecting against accidental misuse (which the language does very well) vs. protecting against deliberate abuse (which is effectively impossible). In the end, if a programmer wants badly enough to subvert the system, he'll find a way"

Comment: There *are* times where you need to sandbox untrusted code, but that is a daunting task. Protecting against error (Murphy) is the far more common case.

Comment: `#define private public` (ignoring that it is actually Undefined Behavior) and voila I have **full access** from outside to the *restricted* part of your classes.

Comment: Protecting against deliberate abuse may be *theoretically* impossible but it is *effectively* possible, by making abuse sufficiently difficult that it happens very rarely. It's important to be clear about that. Otherwise software could not be used at all in situations such as life-critical medical devices.

Comment: @MarkJ. Herb Sutter's remark is about deliberate abuse by the developer who wrote the class in the first place and perhaps his team-mates. I don't think there is a way to prevent that sort of abuse by language features.

Comment: @bolov that stunt is language dependent I think.  While C/C++ preprocessors would probably let you get away with that, anything without them would probably give a "can't use reserved words in a #define" error.

Comment: Upvote for the Murphy quote

Answer (score 10):

No, this is actually an important advantage.  Simply because some developer didn't consider that anyone would need access to some piece of internal state doesn't mean that no legitimate use case will ever turn up.  In these cases, using Reflection to perform surgery on an object can be a last resort.  I've had to use this technique more than once.

Comment: In other words, it is a way of circumventing a likely broken API - whether due to incomplete requirements or incomplete implementation.

Answer (score 4):

You restrict accessibility even more by going up one more level: the execution environment.

Not all languages have this concept, but at least with Java you can use a security manager that forbids making private fields accessible. You could manually install the security manager at runtime, or add a security policy in a jar file which is then sealed to prevent modification.

More information on doing this in Java: [Reflection Security](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14639753)

Answer (score 3):

What reflection are you talking about?

In many reflection systems, circumventing encapsulation is an explicit capability that your code needs to obtain, and doesn't have by default.

If you are concerned about encapsulation, the simple solution is to just not use a reflection system that doesn't preserve it.

Answer (score 3):

In Python, there are no access modifiers. The convention is to prefix by an underscore the methods and variables which are not expected to be accessed from outside of the class. Does it technically prevent you from accessing such field from a third-party class? Not at all; but if you do, you're on your own and you take the risk of breaking something, without being able to blame the other class.

In C#, access modifiers exist, but they are yet only a convention—one which is enforced by a compiler, but still a convention. This means that technically, one can still access and change private variables, either through Reflection or by tampering directly the memory (like [game trainers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trainer_(games)) do). The consequence is exactly the same: if the variables of your class are changed through Reflection from another class, or through memory tampering by another application, and it breaks something in your class, it's not your fault.

Note that this, obviously, creates security issues where a third-party can access *your* data; something which leads to [encrypted variants of a string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx) and similar data structures. But protecting your code from such usage is more related OS and [code-level access restrictions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/930b76w0(v=vs.90).aspx), and has nothing to do with Reflection per se.

Comment: Note that in C#, only fully trusted code can reflect private members. Writing directly to process memory still works, but is *harder* than in native code.